# properly link sub-folders inside my header PHP

Tags: php, html, include, href

I'm having problems properly linking my sub folders as i go deeper in my folder. What i came up with is to put one `header.php` in every sub folders. I tried do this`../../` line. But i'm sure it would destroy my previous page as i'm using only one.

here's my sample code now `../../../../img/dropdown/cars/choose_vios.png`.

Comment: you could always create a constant that is the path to your images folder? And you can leverage this constant value regardless of where you are?

Comment: Try to use absolute url like /url-to/choose_vios.png

Comment: @artgb it would work. but is it viable for live view. is that the right way to do that? i've been reading abouti t. and i think most of people would not recommend that.

Comment: @JParkinson1991 how do i do that ? even if i  my sub folders go deep it will not change?